# Yii2 - Uploading multiple images in the form using kartik fileInput

Tags: file-upload, yii2, widget

Now the problem with [kartik](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput) widget is in the form view after you upload the first photo( before submiting the form) for the other next ones it just gets overwrite on the previous ones and the only preview in the field is for the last uploaded one.

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'image')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
                'name'=> 'ads_photos[]',
                'options'=>['accept'=>'image/*', 'multiple'=>true, ],
                'pluginOptions'=>[
                'allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg','gif','png'],
                'overwriteInitial'=>false,
                ]
            ]); 
        ?>
```

as you can see I've set `'multiple'=>true`, and '`overwriteInitial'=>false,` as far as you can see in the [guide](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput) it has said the same.
but what's the problem?

Comment: have you found the solution i am also facing the same problem

Comment: @Sajid sorry to say that but I changed the whole project. I couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the guide more careful:

Note:
When using the widget to upload multiple files you must name the HTML input in array format by appending [] to the input/attribute name. Check the examples for usage.

Comment: the only thing that guide has mentioned for multiple in the comment on the top the code is: _Set overwrite `initialPreview` to `false` to append uploaded images to the initial preview._ . but anyway I've updated the answer, is that what you mean? and sth else that I have to notice; I am able to upload more than one file in each browsing but I can't do that separately. And in the example there is also a trash icon in each photo, that I don't have it even when I'm using the way I mentioned.

Comment: @Zhang Buzz i have also the same problem could you help here please

Comment: @Sajid, sorry, I have long time not playing with PHP (turning to node.js), I cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried by setting default initial preview. suppose if your widget dont have any previous images then set the default image like we put default avatar for profile photo.

Try this by setting initial preview property

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'image')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
                'name'=> 'ads_photos[]',
                'options'=>['accept'=>'image/*', 'multiple'=>true, ],
                'pluginOptions'=>[
                'allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg','gif','png'],
                'initialPreview'=>[
            "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/FullMoon2010.jpg/631px-FullMoon2010.jpg",
        ],
        'overwriteInitial'=>false,
        'initialPreviewAsData'=>true,
                ]
            ]); 
        ?>
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. The only thing that initial preview did for me is that it puts an image there and nothing is different.

Comment: what version you are using please try to update the extension

Comment: the widget is the latest version and I've recently installed it via composer.